# Search through nested list, find sub-element and remove based on value

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a nested list

```
test_list = [['AA', 'OFF'], ['BB', 'OFF'], ['BB', 'ON'], ['BB', 'ON'], ['CC', 'OFF'], ['DD', 'OFF'], ['EE', 'OFF']]
```

I would like to find matching index 0 sub-elements such as

```
['BB', 'OFF'], ['BB', 'ON'], ['BB', 'ON']
```

and filter out any sub-items with `'OFF'` in index 1 as long as there is a matching index 0 with `' ON'` found and not keep duplicates, otherwise just keep the sub-elements.

So for the above example, the end result would be:

```
[['AA', 'OFF'], ['BB', 'ON'], ['CC', 'OFF'], ['DD', 'OFF'], ['EE', 'OFF']]
```

I tried converting the above to a dictionary but the result changes depending on the chronological order of the list:

```
test_dict = dict(test_list)
test_dict
```

output:

```
{'AA': 'OFF', 'BB': 'ON', 'CC': 'OFF', 'DD': 'OFF', 'EE': 'OFF'}
```

Which is exactly what I want

BUT for

```
test_list1 = [['AA', 'OFF'],['BB', 'ON'],['BB', 'OFF'],['CC', 'OFF'],['DD', 'OFF'],['EE', 'OFF']]
test_dict1 = dict(test_list1)

test_dict1
{'AA': 'OFF', 'BB': 'OFF', 'CC': 'OFF', 'DD': 'OFF', 'EE': 'OFF'}
```

Which neglects `['BB', 'ON']` because of its position and is not fitting to what I want.

The order of the `test_table` list doesn't really matter as long as the end values are unique and meet the 'ON' / 'OFF' criteria above.
I guess I am looking for a way to group and sort the nested list so that I can then turn it into a dictionary and output the desired result?

Comment: what happens when you have two OFF and one ON like this `['BB', 'OFF'], ['BB', 'OFF'], ['BB', 'ON'],`, would you want `ON` or `OFF` ?

Comment: If `ON`  is in the list then it has to be the one displayed and `OFF` should be dropped.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply sort the list on the second element of the sub-lists, so that `ON` always follows `OFF` with the code:

```
test_list1 = [['AA', 'OFF'],['BB', 'ON'],['BB', 'OFF'],['CC', 'OFF'],['DD', 'OFF'],['EE', 'OFF']]
test_dict1 = dict(sorted(test_list1, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Results in `test_dict1` containing:

```
{'AA': 'OFF', 'BB': 'ON', 'CC': 'OFF', 'DD': 'OFF', 'EE': 'OFF'}
```